# randomSurvivalForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm using the randomSurvivalForest package for R, version 3.6.4. I have been using it for a project for a while, with no problem. However, now I have added some additional predictors to my dataset, and find that now some of them are not scored (importance).

It looks like 100 is the magic number; before I had 95 and they were all scored; now I have 110 and the output reports importance values for 100. I have experimented with some of the parameters, including -ntree- and -mtry-; different predictors are omitted, but always 10 of them.

Am I missing something obvious? Or maybe not so obvious? There is no warning or other indication that rsf() has done something with my predictors, and they are still there in the dataframe when rsf() has finished.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The problem seems to be only with `print()`; I can get all of the importance values with `rforest$importance`.